# Dynamic SQL in Python with dynamic Select statement

Tags: python, sql

In Python I want to select a specific value from a dynamic column and wonder, if I can do that using a parameterized statement without using SQLAlchemy - the one below gives me the variable output, not the content of the cell in SQL. If I replace the variable ":map_scenario" behind the "Select" and make it static, it gives me the value from the cell - so it has to have something to do with the variable usage here:

```
self.c.execute("select :map_scenario FROM map_config WHERE map_alias=:sqlmap_alias", {'map_scenario': val_gamemode, 'sqlmap_alias': val_map_alias_result})
```

Any ideas to where I have a wrong concept, are highly appreciated - searching didn't give me a hint, although I tried it with the masking "?" and "%s" - all the same?

Guess SQL doesn't support this kind of injection, so I would have to build the query before I send it for execution, right?

Answer (score 1):

Got it, had to create the SQL statement outside the query and then put it in:

```
val_map_alias_result = (str(val_map_alias[0]))
        query = ("select " + val_gamemode + " FROM map_config WHERE map_alias=:sqlmap_alias")
```

That works perfectly.